# Passing an array into sequential neural network model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, python-imaging-library

So I've followed along with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ8BIBpya2k) video on creating a sequential neural network and giving it the MNIST data set to make predictions on.

I've also got a flask web server and with it I am trying to pass an image that I've gotten from a canvas drawing app, resize it to 20x20 as that's the dimensions of the MNIST images, convert it to grayscale and then into an array using numpy and finally give it to my model and have it make a prediction. I will then pass that back to the webpage.

However I'm getting the error:

```
Error when checking input: expected sequential_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 20)
```

How do I make the array 3 dimensional?

The model:

```
model = kr.models.Sequential() # Create a new sequential neural network
model.add(kr.layers.Flatten()) # Input layer
model.add(kr.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")) # 128 neurons and the 'basic' activation function.
model.add(kr.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(kr.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
```

```
#   Open the image from the request as originalImage
    originalImage = Image.open("theImage.png")

    #   Resize it
    resizedImage = ImageOps.fit(originalImage, dim, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    #   Confirm the dimensions of the resized image
    w1, h1 = resizedImage.size
    print(w1, h1)

    #   Save it locally
    resizedImage.save("resizedImage.png", quality=100, optimize=True)

    #   Convert to grayscale and then convert that to an array
    grayscaleImage = ImageOps.grayscale(resizedImage)
    grayscaleArray = np.array(grayscaleImage)

    print(grayscaleArray.reshape(20, 20, 1))

    setPrediction = model.predict(grayscaleArray)
    getPrediction = np.array(setPrediction[0])

    predictedNumber = str(np.argmax(getPrediction))
    print(predictedNumber)
```

Comment: try reshape to (20, 20, 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `reshape` is not inplace. 
You should do:

```py
grayscaleArray = grayscaleArray.reshape(20, 20, 1)
```

Comment: @Neilk, if this answered your question, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! So now my code looks like so:
```
grayscaleImage = ImageOps.grayscale(resizedImage)
grayscaleArray = np.array(grayscaleImage)
grayscaleArray = grayscaleArray.reshape(20, 20, 1)
setPrediction = model.predict(grayscaleArray)    #  problem is here
getPrediction = np.array(setPrediction[0])


```
I'm still getting the error: Error when checking input: expected sequential_1_input to have shape (28, 28) but got array with shape (20, 1)

I switched it to be 28, 28 and then it says cannot shape an array of size 400 to be (28, 28, 1)

Comment: Hey, so it seems I had the wrong channel format. It no longer gives me an error after reshaping it like: (1, 28, 28)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49057149/expected-conv2d-1-input-to-have-shape-28-28-1-but-got-array-with-shape-1-2

Comment: So the problem is that `predict` works in batch, so you need to provide a batch of data. In this case, indeed you need to shape it like `(1, 28, 28)` which works because your model doesn't expect an image as input (you are flattening the input directly). If your model was for example using a 2D convolution, you would need to shape it like `(1, 28, 28, 1)`.